# how to connect tenant_id to client id/secret for Application Client bsed multi-tenancy on AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saas

I am trying to build a SaaS system for a machine-2-machine authentication scenario, which is exactly the same as described in the document: "You have a B2B multi-tenant application, and tenant backend services use a client-credentials grant to access your services. In this case, you can create an application client for each tenant and share the client-id and secret with the tenant backend service for machine-to-machine authentication."

I think these are the steps:
1, assign one or more client_ids/secrets for a given tenant
2, the tenant calls the /auth2/token api to get an access token
3, use the access JWT token for API authentication

However, I have to recognize the tenant_id from the client_id, for statistics or fees. I guess the best way is to put a tenant_id field in the access token? But how? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In Cognito, adding custom attributes to the access token is not supported. We can add custom attributes only to the `id_token`, not to an `access_token`.

Which actually make sense based on their intended usages. As stated in [Okta documentation](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/validate-id-tokens/main/#id-tokens-vs-access-tokens):

> The ID Token is a security token granted by the OpenID Provider that
> contains information about an End-User.
>
> Access tokens, on the other
> hand, are not intended to carry information about the user. They
> simply allow access to certain defined server resources.

So, the answer is NO, we can not add `tenant_id` field to the `access_token`.

Having said that, if you don't have another option and you really really need this to be in the access token, I can provide a hint which **I don't recommend**:

You can try this with the [Pre token generation lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html). Please note that this lambda trigger is mainly intended to customize the `id_token` claims. However, as stated in the document:

> Amazon Cognito ID and access tokens both contain the cognito:groups claim. Your groupOverrideDetails object replaces the cognito:groups claim in access tokens and ID tokens.

So, you should be able to modify the `cognito:groups` attribute in access token by manipulating `groupOverrideDetails` object.  With that you can try to sneak in `tenant_id` to `cognito:groups` array.

NOTE: I don't recommend this as the `tenant_id` is not a valid group and this can create side effect in the application which can leads to vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks, Sampath! Now I understand the custom attributes are not available. So, what is the best way to match the client_id to the tenant? Get the client_id from the JWT token, and then look up the client_id from the database to find the matched tenant id?

Comment: So, I am planning to give different client credentials to different tenants...

Comment: @Ning how do you plan to deploy APIs that utilize this `access_token`? 
Along with AWS API Gateway?

Comment: yes, use API Gateway for sure. Are there any special configurations?

Comment: by the way, I am planning to give each user a "tenant_id" field, so one user may equal one tenant. But each tenant/user could create many clients(client id and client seret pair), for dev or production or so.

Comment: well I asked about API GW because, then you can have a API GW Lambda Authorizer to validate the token and it can handle this DB lookup and include those details in the response. So you can get these details in the other components. Also this lambda response will be cached and you can avoid DB lookups for every request.
If you can elaborate the question with those details I would happy to update the answer with that.

Comment: It is not a good idea to have one user pool for multiple environments. Having a separate user pool for each environment would be helpful in terms of security, scalability etc.

Comment: Ok, use the lambda authorizer to search the database. Got it, thanks so much!!